# WordPress is not recognizing paragraph elements after h1 elements?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I'm currently in the process of making my own WordPress theme, and I decided to make a complete page to see how things are going.

**What I'm dealing with:**

I started off with a paragraph element containing 'Lorem ipsum...' **before** I included a heading element that said 'home'.

When I opened the page, I noticed that the first paragraph of 'Lorem ipsum...' did not have the designated formatting like it was suppose to.

```
.page-content-left p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

When I opened the HTML, I saw this:

```
<div class="page-text">
    <p></p>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    "
    Lorem ipsum...
    "
    <p></p>
</div>
```

As you can see, "Lorem ipsum..." is not wrapped in a paragraph like it was suppose to be. *Interestingly,* if I add a heading **first**, then add "Lorem ipsum", everything looks fine. But why won't it work the other way around?

Comment: "As you can see, "Lorem ipsum..." is not wrapped in a paragraph like it was suppose to be. " — Why was it supposed to be wrapped in a paragraph? You haven't shown us the input that is causing you this problem. Only the output. (It doesn't even look like you've provided the HTML source code, that looks like it is has been copied from the DOM inspector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatting is targeting a class called "page-content-left"  but the paragraph elements are actually in a class called "page-text"  so that's likely the reason the formatting is not being applied.

Answer (score 0):

I believe those are both block-level elements which are intended to contain inline elements only (spans, i, em, etc).  WordPress may be trying to clean up the inclusion of those two block elements together by separating them.

So, P and Hx should not be nested.